# Django Calendar Widget?

Tags: django, calendar

Does anyone know of any existing packages or libraries that can be used to build a calendar in a django app?

Comment: Calendaring is a vast field.  What features do you need?  Event display?  Export in standard formats?  Appointment scheduling?  Resource scheduling?  Etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quick google search reveals [django-gencal](https://github.com/justinlilly/django-gencal), which looks like exactly what you need.  It would also be worth looking at the snippets under the calendar tag on Django Snippets at http://www.djangosnippets.org/tags/calendar/.

Comment: The link you supply responds with:

Your client does not have permission to get URL /p/django-calendar/ from this server.

Comment: Changed the link to a current project which looks like what the questioner was after.

Comment: It says _For real documentation, see the project's homepage_ but the link to http://code.justinlilly.com/django-gencal/ returns a domain-not-found, and justinlilly.com doesn't refer to it.

Comment: Must have been a temporary glitch, http://code.justinlilly.com/django-gencal/ works for me.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that django-calendar has become django-agenda: http://github.com/dokterbob/django-agenda

Comment: There is also a github https://github.com/noisyboiler/django-calendar, but I'm not sure which one is which since I never saw the original.  I couldn't find any immediate references to a fork from the django-calendar project.

Answer (score 3):

Great Tipps

django-swingtime lives on

http://github.com/dakrauth/django-swingtime

Answer (score 2):

The django-schedule code originally from thauber ([thauber/django-schedule](https://github.com/thauber/django-schedule)) has been forked and worked into the  [glamkit/glamkit-eventtools](https://github.com/glamkit/glamkit-eventtools) code for Galleries, Libraries, Museums and Archives.  It has also been forked and updated by a variety of other folks, e.g. [boskee/django-schedule](https://github.com/boskee/django-schedule), and my guess is that that might have fewer dependencies and be easier to integrate into another project.  It says:

> Django-schedule: A calendaring/scheduling application, featuring:

- one-time and recurring events
- calendar exceptions (occurrences changed or cancelled)
- occurrences accessible through Event API and Period API
- relations of events to generic objects
- ready to use, nice user interface
- view day, week, month, three months and year
- project sample which can be launched immediately and reused in your project

See the github "network" tab for a graphical navigation from the point of view of a given branch to see how other branches relate to it (i.e. what is available for merging).

Comment: Have you played with any of them?

Comment: @Onlyjus Sorry - I have not.  I was just trying to raise the visibility of some of the options in this confusing space.

Answer (score 1):

svn checkout http://django-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ django-calendar-read-only
svn: URL 'http://django-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk' doesn't exist

so google search may reveal, but it's no longer exists.

Comment: The project can only be downloaded as a tarball from the project page.  In other words, they aren't using google code for SVN.

Answer (score 1):

There is another [calendar alternative here](http://www.3captus.com/download/django_calendar), Django Event Calendar from [3captus](http://www.3captus.com/), that offers something a bit simpler. I'm trying it out now, but it looks like a better fit for me.

From the features list:

- Full feature calendar display using python calendar class
- Support month scrolling (forward or backward)
- AJAX add, modify, delete GUI
- Require mimimum knowledge of Django, should be a good compliment after you are done with django tutorial 
    (http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/tutorial01/)
- Calendar and Event class can be used in any python project
- Full unit test included

Answer (score 1):

There are also some calendar functions built into Python itself, you can see a simple implementation [here](http://journal.uggedal.com/creating-a-flexible-monthly-calendar-in-django/).

Comment: You're referring to HTMLCalendar from Python 2.5.  And to clarify, the link shows how that can be incorporated into Django.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into [django-swingtime](http://code.google.com/p/django-swingtime/).  Worth checking out.