# how to handle an event on Django event Calendar

Tags: django, events, calendar

Is there a way to have a django Clandar Event, i have a Event model, and i want to display the event information on the calendar in order to know if the organiser is free or busy on the date event.

Many Thanks.

I didn't find the Django Calendar.
Where can i find some good example please ?

Many thanks

Comment: Have a look at this post, you might find it useful :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224120/django-the-best-solution-for-event-calendar/11816184#11816184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the site and you might just find [what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264/django-calendar-widget).