# django Enter a valid date. validation error

Tags: django

My model

```
 class Member(models.Model):

dob = models.DateField('dob')
```

form

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):
  dob = forms.DateField(required=False, input_formats='%Y-%m-%d')
  class Meta:
    model = Member
    exclude = ('profile',)
```

some view code

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        # Create a formset from the submitted data
        member_formset = MemberFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if signup_form.is_valid() and member_formset.is_valid():
          print 'in valid'
          signup = signup_form.save(request.POST)
          for form in member_formset.forms:
            member = form.save(commit=False)
            member.profile = signup
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            # print member.objects.all()
            member.save()
          return redirect("/main") # Redirect to a 'success' page
```

when m submitting the form the error message coming is

```
Enter a valid date.
```

What should i do to solve this validation .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`input_formats` needs to be a list, see

example:

```
['%Y-%m-%d',      # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y',       # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y']       # '10/25/06'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField

Answer (score 14):

I prefer to set **[DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)
in settings.py and then define the field like:

```
dob = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

This more DRY than setting it on a per form field basis.

If it's a text field input, I almost always put the accepted format(s) in the field's `help_text` so that the user can know what format(s) is(are) accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to add a new field once you already have a `DateField` in your Model.

You just have to set the `input_formats` for this field:

```
self.fields[ 'dob' ].input_formats = [ '%Y-%m-%d' ]
```

References: [DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField) and [Format Localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#format-localization)

Comment: Not sure if it's a Django version or whatever (we are still on 2.2), but this is the only solution I could find to override the input format for a ModelForm DateTimeField.  Creating custom cleaners, settings the global DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS, and a bunch of other methods didn't work, but this one does.

Answer (score 0):

The `input_formats` is your friend.

If you accept javascript, then you could make the field use something like jQuery calendar (i.e. a read-only text field and clicking on it will call the jquery code and pop up the calendar widget). You can have [this calendar widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264/django-calendar-widget) as a starting point.