# __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'input_formats'

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, datefield

forms.py

```
from django import forms

ACCEPTED_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y', '%d.%m.%Y', '%d/%m/%Y']

class LeaveRequestForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=ACCEPTED_FORMATS)
    end_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=ACCEPTED_FORMATS)
    working_days = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)
```

I couldn't find any date format that could pass form validation, every time I received 'Enter a valid date.', so when I tried to define some the exception came out:

```
__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'input_formats'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#datefield

settings.py

...

```
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True
```

...

I also tried built-in SelectDateWidget with no luck, every time produced invalid date. Maybe there is some "cache" issue:
["Enter a valid date" Error in Django Forms DateField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830901/enter-a-valid-date-error-in-django-forms-datefield)

What should I do to get past this validation checks and move on with proper dates? Are the docs missing something with an error I encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input_formats is not a kwarg, it's the sole option to DateField. Drop the `input_formats=`

```
ACCEPTED_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y', '%d.%m.%Y', '%d/%m/%Y']

class LeaveRequestForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(ACCEPTED_FORMATS)
    end_date = forms.DateField(ACCEPTED_FORMATS)
    working_days = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)
```