# django calendar app?

Tags: django, calendar

everyone. I'm developing a meeting room reserving system with django for my company. I need a calender compontent in this system. I want to view my events in daily, weekly and monthly view, just like Google calendar. Is there any existing app helpful to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Calendar Widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264/django-calendar-widget) Did you try searching?

Answer (score 6):

Django's class based views support day, month and year views out-of-the-box. We used these for a simple calendar app in a project ([example](http://www.kortevlietschool.nl/agenda/2012/04/)), works like a charm. We used Python's calendar lib as a starting point for a generic templatetag.

I googled for a similar idea and found this: http://code.google.com/p/django-gencal/

Comment: I have also used django-gencal (based itself on Python's Calendar lib) as a starting point to make my own templatetag: easy and flexible.